# Send xmlhttprequest to a server via another server

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I have tow servers (server A and  B) which can communicate between them and a client that is able to communicate just with sever A and not with B. so I want to known if it is possible to send xmlhttprequest from the client to server A first and after that the server A resend this xmlhttprequest to server B.
Client ==》 server A ==》 server B

Comment: you should give the platform. if its php then you might use curl and in java you can use HttpURLConnection for http request

Comment: Thanks for your response , I am using java script in my html page.